# How can ı get call logs with microsoft graph

Tags: c#, api, http, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am new at microsoft graph api.  I want to get the participants of a Teams meeting, and I can do it by

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/7531d31f-d10d-44de-802f-c569dbca451c/participants
```

No problem so far. But the problem is, in my organisation, there are several groups and lots of meetings.
As an admin, how can I get the ids for the request? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can get the id by using Get [callRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-1-get-basic-details)  .The call record is available only after the associated call is completed.

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT Yes I know that, I have already written the sample request of CallRecord, I think you did not read the body of the question. My question is, how can I get record ids of my organisation from graph api as an admin, I need to get Record id to use callRecord request
Thanks for attention

Comment: hi @HAZAN - There are two ways to get the id. 1. Get the subscription for VTC as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/cloud-video-interop-for-teams-set-up)  2. Get subscription for the notification API so that you will receive the id in the backend and you can get the records of the calls. Please check this [example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample#creating-the-subscription)

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT thank you a lot for the help. I am checking if the links can help me. I will update.